# Shortcut to cycle through windows of the current application

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

In Windows 7/8, multiple instances of the same application (Windows Explorer, for example) will appear in the taskbar under one icon.

Is there a keyboard shortcut that will automatically cycle through the main windows of the various instances of the current process, preferably highlighting their preview window in the taskbar?

I know I can use WIN+# but that requires me to count taskbar items and doesn't scale beyond 10.

(Windows 8 exclusive shortcuts are ok too)

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can use AHK to accomplish this if all else fails.  If all instances have no unique titles or features, there are other variables you can use to sieve the windows (e.g., PID).  If you end up looking to go that route, I'd suggest posting on the AHK Discord for further advice/assistance.

Answer (score 3):

- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to move focus to the taskbar

  - <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to move between applications on the taskbar. (You can also type the first letter of the application title to jump.)
  - <kbd>↑</kbd> to move focus to the subpages/previews

    - <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to move between the subpages/previews

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for something a little more direct if possible.

Comment: @RichardSzalay: Unfortunately it does not seem to be possible to focus the current application right away if i did not miss anything in the official documentation :/

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for on Windows is **Ctrl+Tab** to cycle through the windows of an open application.

Comment: This only works if the application explicitly supports it. Try opening two instances of notepad and then cycle between.